# How to change json date to MM/DD/YY using moment?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Lets say I have this date

```
const date = '2022-05-24T14:52:30.250Z';
```

how would I use moment to check if this is a valid date and convert it to something like 05/24/22?
Thank you for any help and guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const date = '2022-05-24T14:52:30.250Z';
if (moment(date).isValid()) console.log(moment(date).format("MM/DD/YY")
```

Comment: missing parentheses at the end but other than that thank you for the great answer!